# Update multiple records SQL with condition (FIFO)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am sorry before if that title doesn't represent my problem here.

The scenario:

> I do outbound 5 items for ItemA

Table FIFO:

```
| date       | item  | inbound | outbound |
| 13/11/2015 | itemA |    2    |          |
| 15/11/2015 | itemA |    8    |          |
```

My UPDATE script's now (wrong):

```
 | date       | item  | inbound | outbound |
 | 13/11/2015 | itemA |    2    |     5    |
 | 15/11/2015 | itemA |    8    |          |
```

The expected result (right):

```
| date       | item  | inbound | outbound |
| 13/11/2015 | itemA |    2    |     2    |
| 15/11/2015 | itemA |    8    |     3    |
```

I have using SQL Server 2008. My script only UPDATE the first row. How to achieve this with SQL?
I am create the scenario on fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5a5e/13). I don't know some script give an error there but in SQL Server is work.

Thank in advance

Comment: what logic you are using to get data for outbound column. can you share the query?

Comment: Total outbound column should not exceed inbound column. If outbound more than inbound, the leftover must go to the next record. (this is what i need)

Comment: In your example, the outbound is not more than the inbound, but new records are calculated - what is the logic you use in this case? The logic you give would be satisfied if `outbound = inbound -1` were always true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to process record by record. Hope the following code helps you to find the logic.
Assumption only one record per date and there will be inbound for all the items.

```
WHILE @ItemCount>0
BEGIN
SELECT TOP 1 @dat=date,@inbound=inbound FROM FIFO WHERE item='iteamA' AND outbound IS NULL ORDER BY date ASC
IF(@inbound <= @ItemCount)
BEGIN
   UPDATE FIFO SET outbound=@inbound WHERE item='iteamA' and date=@dat      
ELSE
    UPDATE FIFO SET outbound=@ItemCount WHERE item='iteamA' and date=@dat

END
    SET @ItemCount=@ItemCount-@inbound
END
```